# HBASE: is there a way to know how many requests are performed for a table per month?

Tags: hbase

I have an HBase table "Demo" across multiple regions. I can see in the table details page the requests the table have per region, but I am interested to know how many of those requests are for the current month. Is there a way to know?

Comment: are you seeing that on the hbase admin page?

Comment: Its shows total number of requests, but was looking for a more detailed stat